# Failed to chmod user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices NO Such File Or directory

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, xcode8

When i try to run my app in iPhone 6 simulator, i am getting following error. I am using Xcode 8.1 can any one please help me to understand this issue

[image]

Comment: I had this issue as well. Cleaning the project fixed the issue for me.

Comment: To expand on that, it started happening again shortly after my clean. After repeating the process a couple times, quitting Xcode and Simulator, the problem finally stopped coming up (for now).

Comment: Right by quitting XCode resolved my problem too, it's weird.

Comment: I have this issue too. I cannot solved it

Comment: @huync Just delete your app from simulator then run, if it is not solved your issue , reset your simulator ..

Comment: That's XCode for u. Welcome to Apple.

Comment: Can we ask the obvious question here ... why not just delete the cache?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I had this issue, where it would run it every time I deleted the app from the simulator, but when I tried to run it second time this error would show.

I solved it by resetting the iOS Simulator from the top bar menu.

**Xcode 9.0:**
`Hardware` → `Erase All Content and Settings...`

**Pre Xcode 9.0:**
`Simulator` → `Reset Content and Settings...`

Comment: It didn't work for me. I have also deleted the cash but didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this with restart iOS Simulator: Hardware -> Reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this issue by just **rebooting your simulator**. there is no need to reset the simulator.

i have same problem and i have solved it by just `rebooting simulator`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Schema name and Executable file name in plistfile. both should be same.

Comment: What are the exact keys for schema and executable file name?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with an app that contained an embedded Sticker extension.

To work around it I first installed the app without the Sticker extension, I did this by clicking the `Sticker.appex` in the Products group and removing the app 'Target Membership' using the Inspector panel.

Once the app was installed, I could re-toggle the target membership and install the app with the Sticker extension.

Answer (score 0):

#### SOLVED

I'd added ios platform with `sudo`. That why it happened. Now I do it **without sudo**, it works well.

Please follow below steps to fix it:

1. Remove platform (with `sudo`)
   `$ sudo ionic cordova platform rm ios`
2. Add platform (without `sudo`)
   `$ ionic cordova platform add ios`
3. Emulate
   `$ ionic cordova run ios`

Please check for more info:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/4052#issuecomment-352999643

Answer (score -2):

For solving this issue, U need to go for trial n Error. This error generally appears when you directly delete a file but missed to delete its mapping.
So to resolve this, verify all the mappings in 'AddedLib', 'Resources', and 'complied Resources' sec etc.